# Joining a vSphere host to Active Directory if it is already part of an AD enabled vCenter cluster

Tags: active-directory, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Currently our vSphere 5.1 hosts are part of a vCenter 5.1 cluster.  vCenter is already AD enabled so I just need to do a windows authentication to get access to our hosts.

I was wondering, is it also a "best practice" to join each vSphere host to Active Directory as well?  Or is this unnecessary since vCenter is already AD enabled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not necessary and I don't think there really is a "best practice" scenario for this.

The benefit to adding a vSphere host to the domain would be the additional ability to access to your **`host`** via an AD account instead of the host `root` account.  This way if you have multiple users that require it you no longer have to manage the `root` or user credentials on each host, let AD figure that out for you.

The other benefit is if you have a numbskull admin that changes the `root` password and doesn't let anyone know, you still have access to the server via AD credentials.

Comment: Thanks.  Good to know there are two options for authentication.

Comment: On your "other benefit", it's always best to leave root alone and create a new local account for each admin for auditing purposes.

Answer (score 4):

> Or is this unnecessary since vCenter is already AD enabled?

This.

Comment: Just don't lose or forget a way to get root access to the local host if vCenter isn't available (especially helpful if vCenter runs in a VM).

Comment: @TheCleaner - we have admin clusters just for running admin tool VMs such as VC - so we never have TOO far to look for a 'lost' VC.